# WhatsApp web on Google Chrome scanning the QR code do nothing, but it is working on Edge or from another Windows user

Tags: google-chrome, whatsapp, qr-code

I've noticed this issue a week ago, I'm unable to scan the QR code for WhatsApp web on Google Chrome tab, it just does nothing.

1. Tried incognito window in Google Chrome but it doesn't show any signs of working.
   it did work on the Microsoft Edge browser.
2. Tried using CCleaner, to clear browser from anything that could be causing the issue but there's no difference. (removing cookies)
3. Created a new administrator user on the local machine, after opening the Chrome browser for the WhatsApp web my phone did integrate with the QR code and it was working.
4. Uninstalled extensions in Chrome apps such as Authy that was installed recently, the issue persists.
5. I've recently enabled a flag to combine tabs in Google Chrome, I've tried opening a new tab for WhatsApp web which is not combined but it wasn't working from there either. (I didn't try to disable the flag, in order not to lose my tabs organization)

Any suggestions? it's clearly working from another user and from another web browser so anything else I can check on Chrome?

Comment: Can you try disabling all extensions? Also, if it's working from another user, you can always resort to deleting your chrome user data folder.

Comment: It might seem crazy, but since it hasn't been mentioned in the question, can you confirm that the WhatsApp QR code that's generated on Chrome is valid/recognizable? (i.e. try scanning using [Barcode Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android) or other general QR scanner app)